# Launch terminal and 'conda activate env' from bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, datascience-anaconda

I've seen some similar questions on here, but they haven't covered this particular use-case and I haven't been able to make it work on my own.

I'm trying to do the following **using a script**:

1. Open a new terminal in a specific directory (and keep it open)
2. Activate a specific conda environment in that terminal
3. Launch my IDE (atom), also from that terminal

I've tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh    
gnome-terminal --working-directory=~/Desktop/Atom/myEnv/ -e 'conda activate myEnv && atom'
```

But receive this error message:

> Failed to execute child process “conda” (No such file or directory)

I've also tried the following code, which results in a conda not found error:

```
#!/bin/sh
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate myEnv
bash -i
```

The following code opens a terminal and displays the expected python version for that environment, but doesn't carry-over the activation to the 'bash -i' window:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate myEnv
python --version
bash -i
```

Please let me know if there is a simple way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Is `conda` in your `PATH`?

Comment: Yes, both "/home/nate/miniconda3/bin" and "/home/nate/miniconda3/condabin" are on the PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bash`,`zsh` or any shell **aliases** for this purposes. You just add

```
alias my_conda='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38'
```

line into the `.bashrc`,`.zshrc` or `.any_other_shell_rc`.

**"N.B. My environment name is `MyPy38`"**. So,replace it according name as well as the path `/home/$USER/anaconda3`.
Also you can create separate file for aliases. Just create a file called `.bash_aliases` and add

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

lines to `.bashrc`,`.zshrc` or `.any_other_shell_rc` and keep the command

```
alias my_conda='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38'
```

into the `.bash_aliases`. Now,  `source ~/.zshrc ~/.bashrc` or just close and open a new terminal. Run the command `my_conda` and **BOOM!**

Also, you can add some other aliases for `jupyter-notebook` `jupyter-lab` `spyder` etc. like

```
# Just activate my conda
alias my_conda='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38'

# Open Jupyter Notebook in my Env
alias my_jupn='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38 && jupyter-notebook'

# Open Jupyter Lab in my Env
alias my_jupl='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38 && jupyter-lab'

# Open Spyder in my Env
alias my_spyder='source /home/$USER/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate MyPy38 && spyder'
```

To confirm active environment name python code

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```